# Unknown wire in septic tank pump installation

Tags: septic

I have a septic lift pump station. When I open the outdoor control box I find one wire-nut connection connecting the 12V 14-2 wire from indoor low voltage alarm box with wire to high level float that goes inside tank.This seems normal.
There is a second wire-nut connection with 3ea. 14-2 wires connected together. One 14-2 wire comes from 110V breaker panel switch #7 and is supply. One 14-2 wire goes to a plug inside weather proof box and is what the pump and piggyback on/ off float plug into to make septic pump work. I cannot figure what the third 14-2 wire goes to? It does however have a short piece of electricians tape wrapped around white lead and a short piece or electricians tape wrapped around black lead as a clue.
Any ideas where this last 14-2 pair might go to?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There's no way we could tell you without more info (e.g. pictures of inside the control box). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: With the white taped black it could be a switch loop there may be a low level switch to turn off the pump.